# Spark pivot table not working with expression maps

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a representation of problem I'm trying to solve. I have a dataframe and I need to pivot it. With that I need to apply different aggregation functions on different columns.

This example I'm pivoting a df on freqency of nos:

```
val unique_nos = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)

val df = Seq(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4).toDF("nos")

df.groupBy("nos").pivot("nos", unique_nos).agg(count(col("nos"))).show(10)
```

This gives output as

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
|nos|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   3|null|null|null|
|  3|null|null|   3|null|
|  4|null|null|null|   1|
|  2|null|   4|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

This is cool but I need to apply seperate agg functions to separate columns so this time i do something like this(for simplicity I am mapping same function to all the cols. In reality I'll be making a seq with different agg functions assigned):

```
val unique_nos = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)

val exprs1 = unique_nos.map(_.toString -> "count").toMap

val df = Seq(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4).toDF("nos")

df.groupBy("nos").pivot("nos", unique_nos).agg(exprs1).show(10)
```

But this throws an error -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "1" among (nos);
```

Any clue about what I might be missing?

Comment: You only have a single column `nos`, when performing the aggregation column 1,2,3,4 are not created yet.

Comment: @Shaido But as you see in the first snippet, I haven't created columns 1,2,3,4 there, but still the first snippet works.